# Stretch CSS Background Image

Tags: css

Possibly a but unusual - I am looking to stretch a background image in css to cover the whole div. I don't want any of the image cropped (so can't use `cover` as I currently have) - I want the background image to distort to fill the div no matter the size / aspect ratio of the div.

I have a codepen here: http://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/ezOrmB

My current code is:

HTML:

```
<div class="background"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/800/400);
}
```

Ideally I would like to do this without Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok but then its getting stretched not proportionally:

```
div.background {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/800/400);
}
```

cheers

Comment: As far as I understand that's what he wants

Comment: yes, i didnt saw your comment when i writing this - your totally right!

Answer (score 0):

Set your background size to 100% for both dimensions:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```